# Limit of a certain function

Tags: limits

My analysis book gives two definitions of a function approaching a limit $l$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$.

1. For all $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $x_0-\delta<x<x_0+\delta$ then $l-\epsilon<f(x)<l+\epsilon$.
2. If $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ is a sequence which converges to $x_0$ then the sequence $f(x_1),f(x_2),f(x_3),\ldots$ converges to $l$.

Is there a proof that these definitions are equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1$\implies$ 2:

consider a sequence $x_n\to x_0$. Then for $n$ big enough you have 
$x_n-\delta<x_0<x_n+\delta$ and then $l-\epsilon<f(x_n)<x+\epsilon$, so 
$f(x_n)\to l$.

2$\implies$ 1:

If 1 is false, there is a certain $r>0$ such as for every $\delta$, there is
$x_\delta$ for which
$$
x_\delta -\delta < x_0 < x_\delta +\delta\\
f(x_\delta) > f(x)+r\ \ \ \text{ or }  \ \ \ f(x_\delta)  <f(x) - r
$$
Consider the sequence $x_{\frac 1n}$ ($\delta = \frac 1n$).

Then $x_\frac 1n\to x_0$ and $f(x_{\frac 1n})\nrightarrow l$, so 2 is false.